# save url as a file name in python

Tags: python

I have a url such as

```
http://example.com/here/there/index.html
```

now I want to save a file and its content in a directory. I want the name of the file to be :

```
http://example.com/here/there/index.html
```

but I get error, I'm guessing that error is as the result of `/`  in the url name.

This is what I'm doing at the moment.

```
with open('~/' + response.url, 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.body)
```

any ideas how I should do it instead?

Comment: `I want the name of the file to be :...` why?

Comment: That's what I thought and then my answer was downvotet :D I think a lot of problems just exists because there is a suitable detour in one's head.

Comment: @njzk2 well the reason was I gonna download several pages in a folder, it would be much easier to refer to a url if you have the name of the as the file name. this way I don't have to do some crazy hashMap (or something else) to each file

Comment: so what you actually want is a filename that is uniquely related to the filename without any extra data. the answer from @ReutSharabani is a good solution

Comment: @njzk2 yeah pretty much, as index.html won't be unique. answer from Reut Sharabani was great but unfortunately encoder results can sometime contain **/** which produces same problem

Comment: If you need just the one way from url to filename you could also use the hash as filename.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have several problems. One of them is that Unix shell abbreviations (`~`) are not going to be auto-interpreted by Python as they are in Unix shells.

The second is that you're not going to have good luck writing a file path in Unix that has embedded slashes. You will need to convert them to something else if you're going to have any luck of retrieving them later. You could do that with something as simple as `response.url.replace('/','_')`, but that will leave you with many other characters that are also potentially problematic. You may wish to "sanitize" all of them on one shot. For example:

```
import os
import urllib

def write_response(response, filedir='~'):
    filedir = os.path.expanduser(dir)
    filename = urllib.quote(response.url, '')
    filepath = os.path.join(filedir, filename)
    with open(filepath, "w") as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

This uses `os.path` functions to clean up the file paths, and `urllib.quote` to sanitize the URL into something that could work for a file name. There is a corresponding `unquote` to reverse that process.

Finally, when you write to a file, you may need to tweak that a bit depending on what the responses are, and how you want them written. If you want them written in binary, you'll need `"wb"` not just `"w"` as the file mode. Or if it's text, it might need some sort of encoding first (e.g., to `utf-8`). It depends on what your responses are, and how they are encoded.

Edit: [In Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31827113/), `urllib.quote` is now `urllib.parse.quote`.

Comment: thanks alot mate, eventhough @Reut Sharabani answer was great, this is better and more robost

Answer (score 33):

You could use the reversible [base64](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) encoding.

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode('http://example.com/here/there/index.html')
'aHR0cDovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tL2hlcmUvdGhlcmUvaW5kZXguaHRtbA=='
>>> base64.b64decode('aHR0cDovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tL2hlcmUvdGhlcmUvaW5kZXguaHRtbA==')
'http://example.com/here/there/index.html'
```

or perhaps [binascii](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html)

```
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'http://example.com/here/there/index.html')
'687474703a2f2f6578616d706c652e636f6d2f686572652f74686572652f696e6465782e68746d6c'
>>> binascii.unhexlify('687474703a2f2f6578616d706c652e636f6d2f686572652f74686572652f696e6465782e68746d6c')
'http://example.com/here/there/index.html'
```

Comment: I wish I could double vote you mate, +10 for answering what I was looking for . it worked like a charm

Comment: I'm assuming this solution would be used for more than 1 URL. However, seeing as `base64` encoding/decoding is not unique (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429168/is-a-base64-encoded-string-unique), then you could end up having different URL overwriting each other!

Comment: Also, couldn't you easily have issues with file length if encoding longer URLs (https://serverfault.com/questions/9546/filename-length-limits-on-linux)?

Comment: I would really fix these issues or refer to the accepted answer as being the better solution.

Comment: You **could** have many problems with the accepted answer as well (and very much the same). Can you give an example of an actual problem here that isn't a problem in the accepted answer?

Comment: I used this code for a large number of URLs and found that some of them got encoded to strings that were too long. I don't have the same issue with the accepted answer. I don't think the accepted answer has an issue with the encoding/decoding not being unique, which this one has (see the link I posted in another comment).

Comment: can you give an example of it not being unique? remember - you can have multiple results per filename if you can decode it.

Comment: About length: the accepted answer has the same flaw. The generated filrname will be longer than the url as well.

Comment: yay to `binascii`, `base64.b64encode` uses `/` so its a no go on linux for filenames

Answer (score 5):

This is a bad idea as you will hit 255 byte limit for filenames as urls tend to be very long and even longer when b64encoded!

You can compress and b64 encode but it won't get you very far:

```
from base64 import b64encode 
import zlib
import bz2
from urllib.parse import quote

def url_strategies(url):
    url = url.encode('utf8')
    print(url.decode())
    print(f'normal  : {len(url)}')
    print(f'quoted  : {len(quote(url, ""))}')
    b64url = b64encode(url)
    print(f'b64     : {len(b64url)}')
    url = b64encode(zlib.compress(b64url))
    print(f'b64+zlib: {len(url)}')
    url = b64encode(bz2.compress(b64url))
    print(f'b64+bz2: {len(url)}')
```

Here's an average url I've found on angel.co:

```
URL = 'https://angel.co/job_listings/browse_startups_table?startup_ids%5B%5D=972887&startup_ids%5B%5D=365478&startup_ids%5B%5D=185570&startup_ids%5B%5D=32624&startup_ids%5B%5D=134966&startup_ids%5B%5D=722477&startup_ids%5B%5D=914250&startup_ids%5B%5D=901853&startup_ids%5B%5D=637842&startup_ids%5B%5D=305240&tab=find&page=1'
```

And even with b64+zlib it doesn't fit into 255 limit:

```
normal  : 316
quoted  : 414
b64     : 424
b64+zlib: 304
b64+bz2 : 396
```

Even with the best strategy of zlib compression and b64encode you'd still be in trouble.

### Proper Solution

Alternatively what you should do is hash the url and attach url as file attribute to the file:

```
import os
from hashlib import sha256

def save_file(url, content, char_limit=13):
    # hash url as sha256 13 character long filename
    hash = sha256(url.encode()).hexdigest()[:char_limit]
    filename = f'{hash}.html'
    # 93fb17b5fb81b.html
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)
    # set url attribute
    os.setxattr(filename, 'user.url', url.encode())
```

and then you can retrieve the url attribute:

```
print(os.getxattr(filename, 'user.url').decode())
'https://angel.co/job_listings/browse_startups_table?startup_ids%5B%5D=972887&startup_ids%5B%5D=365478&startup_ids%5B%5D=185570&startup_ids%5B%5D=32624&startup_ids%5B%5D=134966&startup_ids%5B%5D=722477&startup_ids%5B%5D=914250&startup_ids%5B%5D=901853&startup_ids%5B%5D=637842&startup_ids%5B%5D=305240&tab=find&page=1'
```

*note: setxattr and getxattr require `user.` prefix in python*
for file attributes in python see related issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56399698/3737009

Answer (score 0):

Using [urllib.urlretrieve:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html)

```
import urllib
    
testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve("http://example.com/here/there/index.html", "/tmp/index.txt")
```

Comment: what I like to do, is to be able to refer back to the file that i've created, is it possible to change **/** to something like **\/** instead?

Answer (score -1):

May look into [restricted charaters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved%5Fcharacters%5Fand%5Fwords).

I would use a typical folder struture for this task. If you will use that with a lot of urls it will get somehow or other a mess. And you will run into filesystem performance issues or limits as well.