# ImportError: cannot import name 'quote' from 'urllib' (/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/__init__.py)

Tags: python, urllib, praat

i am using praat from parselmouth in gooogle colab and i am getting this error when importing **from parselmouth.praat import call**

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/parselmouth/adapters/dfp/interface.py in <module>()
     15 from datetime import timedelta
     16 from pytz import timezone
---> 17 from urllib import quote
     18 
     19 # Parselmouth Imports

ImportError: cannot import name 'quote' from 'urllib' (/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/__init__.py)
```

i tried installing diffirent version of urllib but nothing worked

i know that urllib uses  `import urllib.parse.quote` instead of`from urllib import quote`   but i am not the one importing the urllib package it s the praat module and i cannot change it

Comment: As far as I know, `urllib` hasn't had `quote` as a direct member since Python 2. In Python 3, it's `urllib.parse.quote`. Are you sure the package that contains that import is compatible with the version of Python you're using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Importing urllib.quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827012/python-importing-urllib-quote)

Comment: unfortunately no the parselmouth module imports the urllib package that way and i cannot change it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by running `pip uninstall parselmouth`, then `pip install praat-parselmouth`

Some info [here](https://parselmouth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)

Also see this [Github issue](https://github.com/YannickJadoul/Parselmouth/issues/10)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [`urllib` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote), you'll find that the `quote()` function is part of the `urllib.parse` module. Thus:

```py
from urllib.parse import quote
```

Comment: i know but  the parselmouth module imports the urllib package that way and i cannot change it