# Python add custom property/metadata to file

Tags: python, file, metadata

In Python, is it possible to add custom property/metadata to a file?
For example, I need to add "FileInfo" as a new property of the file.
I need a method that works on various file formats

Comment: When you say "to a file", are you referring to the Python `file` object or to the file itself ?

Answer (score 12):

**Heads up: this answer only works on Linux**

You can make use of [extended file attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes) which is a filesystem feature that do just what you want: store custom metadata along files.

In Python, this is implemented by the `os` module through [`setxattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.setxattr) and  [`getxattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getxattr) functions.

```
import os

os.setxattr('foo.txt', 'user.bar', b'baz')
os.getxattr('foo.txt', 'user.bar')  # => b'baz'
```

Note that you must prepend the xattr value with `"user."` otherwise this may raise an `OSError`.

Comment: Note that the attribute is not copied if the file is copied to a new place. But moving will keep the attribute, even moving between volumes.

Comment: Sucks it doesn't stay when copying files.

Comment: @LewisMorris You should use `shutil.copy2()` or `cp -a` which will try to preserve extended attributes.