# Add Metadata to File

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way in Python to add metadata to a file. For example, if I wanted to add a property "source" with a value of "friend" to a file called "CookingRecipe.txt", the end result should be that when I right-click on "CookingRecipe.txt", go to Properties, and go to the "Details" tab, I should see a "Property" below called "source" followed by a "Value" right next to it called "friend".

Here is my code. When the file gets created, I don't see the "source" property with the "friend" value added.

```
f = open("CookingRecipe.txt", "x")
f.fileinfo = {'source': 'friend'}
f.close()
```

Please help and thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python add custom property/metadata to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183819/python-add-custom-property-metadata-to-file)

Comment: @buraequete: I tried the suggested method in that link but it didn't work for me. I'm trying to do this on Windows.

Comment: Related? [Reading metadata with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12521525/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea: Thanks for the link, but I'd like to be able to "add" metadata to a new or old file.

Comment: @qccaprospect Yeah, the link mentions some APIs for *getting* metadata, so *setting* metadata should be similar I'd think.