# Include additional information to a File sent to Django Rest Framework

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

Like sait in the question. I am posting a array of files to my DRF backend.
I would like to include some additional informations to some of the files being send.
The simplest possible solution would be to append additional info to the file itself, although when I try attaching additional attribute to the file object in JavaScript, Python still receives the same standard TemporaryUploadedFile which does not include the additional data.
Is there a reliable solution to this problem  ?

Comment: i think what you looking for is adding metadata to a file, you can take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56399698/11225821

Comment: @LinhNguyen this solution implies adding metadata to the file on the Django side while I need to append the data in a JavaScript request, and receive it in a Django view

Comment: you can also add it on js side too, just google for how to add metadata to a file. Metadata itself is always present in a file