# How to save a file with a URL name?

Tags: python

I'm saving HTTP request as an HTML page.
How can I save the HTML file with the name of the URL.

I'm using Linux OS

So the file name will look like this:  "http://www.test.com.html"

My code:

```
url = "http://www.test.com"
page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
f = open("./file.html", "w")
f.write(page)
f.close()
```

Comment: What OS are you using? At least on Windows this is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [save url as a file name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253530/save-url-as-a-file-name-in-python)

Comment: RTFM: https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot save a file with a url name. The character "/" is not allowed in Windows file names.

However, you can create a file with the name `www.test.com.html` with the following line

```
file_name = url.split('/')[2]
```

If you need to anything like `https://www.test.com/posts/1`, you can try to replace `/` with another custom character that usually not occurs in url such as `__`

```
url = 'https://www.test.com/posts/11111111'
file_name = '__'.join(url.split('/')[2:])
```

Will result in

```
www.test.com__posts__1
```

Comment: I'm using Linux OS

Comment: I'm using Linux OS, how can I save the file with the complete URL?
for example:  "http://www.test.com/djgfdhb989"

Comment: I did not try in Linux since I do not have my computer right now. But if my memory serves me right, you cannot either save it this way.
I am editing my answer to help you find a workaround